# Expand on click and change text

Tags: javascript, jquery

On [this page](https://mse47-mecanosoudure-fr.mon.world/activites) on "En savoir plus" click i expand the .item-collapse div and when the div is open i change the text "En savoir plus" in "Fermer" but
his only work with last item !

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.item-container').click(function() {
      var link = jQuery(this);
      jQuery('.item-collapse').slideToggle('800', function() {
          if (jQuery(this).is(':visible')) {
            link.html('<span  class="icon"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> Fermer</span>');
          } else {
            link.html('<span  class="icon"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> En savoir 
              plus < /span>');
            };
          });
        var $this = jQuery(this).next(); jQuery(".item-collapse").not($this).hide();
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `class` with `click` function and `slideToggle`. When you click one of the divs, it acts like you click all of them.

Eiter use `id` for event handler or give `onClick` to every div you want to click and call your span change function.